# Syncing time for measuring the parallax of Mars

Tags: history, time, parallax

I read somewhere (I can't remember the website) that when Cassini and Jean Richer measured the parallax of Mars, they used Jupiter's (or maybe Saturn's) moons to sync their time. How was this done?

Comment: This is certainly on-topic here, but just fyi there is also [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) as well. If you don't receive an answer after some period of time, you might consider moving this question there.

Comment: Wild guess:  the angular separation  of these observers when, say, a Saturnian moon initates occultation is in the noise compared with their parallax when observing Mars.